# Does "Ingenious Jury-Rig" block cards from returning to their owners pile

Tags: star-trek-ccg

When [Ingenious Jury-Rig](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=3434) is revealed from the Dilemma Stack and placed into my core, does it then stop the effect of returning dilemmas (example [Authenticate Artifacts](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=457) )?

Or does it only prevent actions like [The Manheim Effect](https://www.trekcc.org/2e/index.php?mode=card&cardID=842)?

Answer (score 1):

> Non-Persistent dilemmas may not be returned to your dilemma pile from
>   beneath your opponent's incomplete missions.

Dilemmas that return themselves never go "beneath your opponent's incomplete missions", so they are unaffected.